# Match Distinct Count from Multiple Arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Now I have a collection `col` including docs like follows:

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "shares": [{
            "fundcode": "000001",     
            "lastshares": 1230.20,
            "agencyno": "260",
            "netno": "260"
        },{
            "fundcode": "000002",
            "lastshares": 213124.00,
            "agencyno": "469",
            "netno": "001"
        },{
            "fundcode": "000003",
            "lastshares": 10000.80,
            "agencyno": "469",
            "netno": "002"
        }
    ],
    "trade": [{
            "fundcode": "000001",
            "c_date": "20160412",
            "agencyno": "260",
            "netno": "260",
            "bk_tradetype": "122",
            "confirmbalance": 1230.20,
            "cserialno": "10110000119601",
            "status": "1"
        },{
            "fundcode": "000002",
            "c_date": "20160506",
            "agencyno": "469",
            "netno": "001",
            "bk_tradetype": "122",
            "confirmbalance": 213124.00,
            "cserialno": "10110000119602",
            "status": "1"
        },{
            "fundcode": "000003",
            "c_date": "20170507",
            "agencyno": "469",
            "netno": "002",
            "bk_tradetype": "122",
            "confirmbalance": 10000.80,
            "netvalue": 1.0000,
            "cserialno": "10110000119602",
            "status": "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

how can I realize a selection like the following sql using mongodb query?:

```
SELECT _id
FROM col 
WHERE col.shares.lastshares > 1000 
  AND col.trade.agencyno = '469'
GROUP BY _id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT col.shares.fundcode) > 2
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT col.trade.fundcode) > 2
```

I tried the `$unwind`, `$groupby`, `$match` aggregate pipeline twice, but I did not get the right answer. Thanks for help.

Comment: What is the desired output of the query / aggregation? Could you share what you have already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't really help that the supplied sample does not meet the conditions, but of course only because the `"trade"` array would only produce `2` distinct matches which is not enough to meet the *"greater than 2"` constraint in the query.

The structure is certainly different than in an RDBMS, so "sub-queries" do not apply, but at least you made these array. But ideally we would not use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) here at all.

And therefore all we need to do is "count" the "distinct" matches from within the arrays. This can basically be applied within a [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/), [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) as the main operations:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "shares.lastshares": { "$gt": 1000 },
    "trade.agencyno": "469"
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$gt": [
            { "$size": {
              "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                  "input": "$shares",
                  "as": "el",
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": {
                      "if": { "$gt": [ "$$el.lastshares", 1000 ] },
                      "then": "$$el.fundcode",
                      "else": false
                    }
                  }
                }},
                [false]
              ]           
            }},
            2     
          ]},
          { "$gt": [
            { "$size": {    
              "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                  "input": "$trade",
                  "as": "el",
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": {
                      "if": { "$eq": [ "$$el.agencyno", "469" ] },
                      "then": "$$el.fundcode",
                      "else": false
                    }  
                  }
                }},
                [false]
              ]  
            }},
            2
          ]}
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    } 
  }},
  /*
  { "$addFields": {
    "shares": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$shares",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": { "$gt": [ "$$el.lastshares", 1000 ] }
      }
    },
    "trade": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$trade",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.agencyno", "469" ] }   
      }
    }
  }}
  */
])
```

That makes it basically compatible with MongoDB 2.6 and upwards, and only adding the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) in there so you could see the results of the "filter" at least, but it's not needed since that is not what the query in the question asks for, which is in fact "just the document `_id`", but just returning the whole document takes less work. Add a [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) for just the `_id` on the end if you really want that.

Also, to taste you can use [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) instead with MongoDB 3.x releases, but the syntax in this case is actually a little longer:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "shares.lastshares": { "$gt": 1000 },
    "trade.agencyno": "469"
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$gt": [
            { "$size": {
              "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                  "input": { 
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$shares",
                      "as": "el",
                      "cond": { "$gt": [ "$$el.lastshares", 1000 ] }
                    }
                  },
                  "as": "el",
                  "in": "$$el.fundcode"
                }},
                []
              ]           
            }},
            2     
          ]},
          { "$gt": [
            { "$size": {    
              "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                  "input": {
                    "$filter": {
                      "input": "$trade",
                      "as": "el",
                      "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.agencyno", "469" ] }   
                    }
                  },
                  "as": "el",
                  "in": "$$el.fundcode"       
                }},
                []
              ]  
            }},
            2
          ]}
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    } 
  }},
  /*
  { "$addFields": {
    "shares": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$shares",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": { "$gt": [ "$$el.lastshares", 1000 ] }
      }
    },
    "trade": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$trade",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.agencyno", "469" ] }   
      }
    }
  }}
  */
])
```

The basic principles here is the part with:

```
 having (count(distinct fundcode))...
```

Is being achieved by [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) and [`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) to the "filtered" array content by the conditions. And in fact the "GROUP BY"parts are not even required, since the "array" represents the relationship in a "grouped" form already. Think of the overall `$redact` statement as the "HAVING" here.

---

If your MongoDB is truly ancient and you cannot use those forms, then it still is possible with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). And this time we [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/) to get the "distinct" entries:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "shares.lastshares": { "$gt": 1000 },
    "trade.agencyno": "469"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$shares" },
  { "$match": {
    "shares.lastshares": { "$gt": 1000 },
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "shares": { "$addToSet": "$shares.fundcode" },
    "trade": { "$first": "$trade" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$trade" },
  { "$match": {
    "trade.agencyno": "469"      
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "shares": { "$first": "$shares" },
    "trade": { "$addToSet": "$trade.fundcode" }  
  }},
  { "$match": {
    "shares.2": { "$exists": true },
    "trade.2": { "$exists": true }  
  }}
])
```

Where in this case the "HAVING" is represented by the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) clause, where the notations such as `"shares.2": { "$exists": true }` actually ask if the array being tested actually has a "third index", which in turn means it has *"greater than two"*, which is the point of the condition.

---

### But the document only has "two" matches

As noted it would have helped your question if you actually supplied a document that matched the conditions you asked for. Unfortunately the supplied document falls short of the required number of matches for the `"trade"` array in the document.

Fixing your condition to match the supplied document we make it rather `$gte` for greater than or equal to `2` on the `"trade"` conditions:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "shares.lastshares": { "$gt": 1000 },
    "trade.agencyno": "469"
  }},
  { "$redact": {
    "$cond": {
      "if": {
        "$and": [
          { "$gt": [
            { "$size": {
              "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                  "input": "$shares",
                  "as": "el",
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": {
                      "if": { "$gt": [ "$$el.lastshares", 1000 ] },
                      "then": "$$el.fundcode",
                      "else": false
                    }
                  }
                }},
                [false]
              ]           
            }},
            2     
          ]},
          { "$gte": [
            { "$size": {    
              "$setDifference": [
                { "$map": {
                  "input": "$trade",
                  "as": "el",
                  "in": {
                    "$cond": {
                      "if": { "$eq": [ "$$el.agencyno", "469" ] },
                      "then": "$$el.fundcode",
                      "else": false
                    }  
                  }
                }},
                [false]
              ]  
            }},
            2
          ]}
        ]
      },
      "then": "$$KEEP",
      "else": "$$PRUNE"
    } 
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "shares": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$shares",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": { "$gt": [ "$$el.lastshares", 1000 ] }
      }
    },
    "trade": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$trade",
        "as": "el",
        "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.agencyno", "469" ] }   
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Which outputs in that form as:

```
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "shares" : [ 
        {
            "fundcode" : "000001",
            "lastshares" : 1230.2,
            "agencyno" : "260",
            "netno" : "260"
        }, 
        {
            "fundcode" : "000002",
            "lastshares" : 213124.0,
            "agencyno" : "469",
            "netno" : "001"
        }, 
        {
            "fundcode" : "000003",
            "lastshares" : 10000.8,
            "agencyno" : "469",
            "netno" : "002"
        }
    ],
    "trade" : [ 
        {
            "fundcode" : "000002",
            "c_date" : "20160506",
            "agencyno" : "469",
            "netno" : "001",
            "bk_tradetype" : "122",
            "confirmbalance" : 213124.0,
            "cserialno" : "10110000119602",
            "status" : "1"
        }, 
        {
            "fundcode" : "000003",
            "c_date" : "20170507",
            "agencyno" : "469",
            "netno" : "002",
            "bk_tradetype" : "122",
            "confirmbalance" : 10000.8,
            "netvalue" : 1.0,
            "cserialno" : "10110000119602",
            "status" : "1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Or with the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), relax the length to test for `2` positions:

```
db.getCollection('collection').aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "shares.lastshares": { "$gt": 1000 },
    "trade.agencyno": "469"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$shares" },
  { "$match": {
    "shares.lastshares": { "$gt": 1000 },
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "shares": { "$addToSet": "$shares.fundcode" },
    "trade": { "$first": "$trade" }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$trade" },
  { "$match": {
    "trade.agencyno": "469"      
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "shares": { "$first": "$shares" },
    "trade": { "$addToSet": "$trade.fundcode" }  
  }},
  { "$match": {
    "shares.2": { "$exists": true },
    "trade.1": { "$exists": true }  
  }}
])
```

Which returns:

```
{
    "_id" : 1.0,
    "shares" : [ 
        "000003", 
        "000002", 
        "000001"
    ],
    "trade" : [ 
        "000003", 
        "000002"
    ]
}
```

But of course both identify the "document" to the conditions which is what the original query asks, and therefore it's the same basic result regardless of content returned. Which you can alwauys [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) as just the `_id` if you must.

Comment: what if i change the sql from above to this: select _id from col where col.shares.lastshares>1000 and col.trade.agencyno='469' group by _id having count(distinct col.shares.fundcode)>2 and sum(col.trade.confirmbalance)>1000 , how to change the sql?

Comment: @Clark.Xu If you have a new question then [Ask a New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), which is how things work here and it makes it clear what you are asking by doing that. You really should be able to look at the listing here and work out where the difference would be applied. But if you cannot, then post a new question.